# Normal Fan Speed for an early 2011 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

I have an early 2011 Macbook Pro and I noticed today, strangely for the first time, that the fan(s) are always running and audible. I have to admit that I usually have some background noise when using that machine but I've noticed the fan noise now that it's quiet.

I checked the RPMs and they are both (left/right side) at 1995-2000 and CPU temperature is ~36℃ - which all seems like normal readings to me but just to make sure, the fans *do* run all the time, right and for an idle machine (10.9.2 on it with nothing else running) fans running at 2000 rpms is normal.. or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laptop fans are **very** small compared to their desktop counterparts, and require a much higher speed to displace a sufficient amount of air.

- 2,000 RPM is the MINIMUM speed for MacBook fans, with the max being 6,200 RPM.
- Typical operating temperature of a MacBook CPU is between 35℃ and 85℃

Comment: nice and to the point (+1)

Comment: Perfect - thanks for the thorough information!